# Combobox with radiobutton in windows store app

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a windows store app (C# and XAML) and I have customized my combobox by adding radiobutton to it code for which is below:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbSelectLocation" Height="55" Margin="10,10,10,10" Background="#eaeaea" BorderBrush="#eaeaea" PlaceholderText="Location" LostFocus="cmbSelectLocation_LostFocus">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#eaeaea" IsTapEnabled="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="55" >
                 <RadioButton GroupName="grpLocation" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Click="RadioButton_Click" ClickMode="Press" />
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" SelectionHighlightColor="Blue" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,10,20,10"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

which looks like this on running the app:

[image]

My Issues is on click of the radio button the item is selected but my radio button doesn't show up as checked and looks something like this

[image]

Can anybody suggest me what should be done, I tried to manually set it to checked on its click but all it does is show the radio button as selected when I expand the combobox (clicking of "V" arrow)

Comment: Give [ClickMode="Press"]( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.buttonbase.clickmode.ASPx)a shot on your RadioButton

Comment: I have added that @ChrisW. It is part of my code I have pasted above

Comment: no @ChrisW. it didn't work, it is part of my code which I have used in my question.. I didn't edit it..

Comment: Ah well dang, I use that trick for like ListBox items, thought it might work here also. However if it were me I'd probably just make my own thing that only looked/behaved like a combobox, but you might try something like shown here since SL is often much like RT.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisW. appreciate you trying to help me out... will try for some more time, If it doesn't work I well might remove the radio button and will go with the built in combo box without the data template part

Comment: One thing you could do is to use a binding for the values and IsSelected (you'll have to use a converter). Then when you select an item it will automatically update the radio button.

Comment: @NateDiamond will try that and let you know

Comment: @NateDiamond that didn't work, I removed radiobuttons and have now implemented the native combobox..